# Concatenate binding text and static text in source image

Tags: c#, binding, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to concatenate binding text with a static text in source image
For example:

```
<Image Name="ImagePlace" Source="http://site.com/image/architecture.png"  Grid.Column="0" />
<Image Name="ImagePlace" Source="{Binding Path=Ico}"  Grid.Column="0" />
```

And i would like to concatenate the two sources.

I have a list of object named Category that contains a field Icon that contains for example "architecture.png". I bind it in a list.
The url of site doesn't change but the image changes always.

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListboxCategories">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Name="category" Tag="{Binding Path=Id}" Tap="category_Tap_1">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Name="ImagePlace" Source="http://www.test.com/assets/images/icons/tags/architecture.png"  Grid.Column="0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            <Image Name="chevron" Grid.Column="2" Source="/Assets/AppBar/White/appbar.chevron.right.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="50" Height="50" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way (well, depending on your architecture) would be to add a property in your object to do the concatenation:

```
public string FullUri 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return "http://site.com/image/" + this.Ico 
    } 
}
```

Another way is to use a custom converter to do the concatenation.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return "http://site.com/image/" + value.ToString(); 
}
```